# Paginating Multiple Objects of the Same Model on the Same Page with Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, erb, kaminari

**Background**

In my website, I'm trying to display 2 tables with data that I have scraped from another website and have place into an object called Product. The Product object has 2 categories which are stored as enums, registered and unregistered.

**Problem**

The problem comes when I apply pagination with Kaminari. Below are some images to demonstrate the problem.

Before the problem:
[image: Before the problem]

When I click '2' on the Registered Products table, the Unregistered Products table also goes to '2'

Problem:
[image: Problem]

I'm guessing it's because the data from both tables come from the same object? Anyway below are the relevant files.

*My Model*

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
enum product_type: [:registered, :unregistered, :cosmetic]

paginates_per 8
end
```

*My Controller*

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @registered_products = Product.where(product_type: 0).page params[:page]
  @unregistered_products = Product.where(product_type: 1).page params[:page]
 end
end
```

*My partial for registered products*

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope='col'>Name</th>
      <th scope='col'>Chemical</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @registered_products.each do |product| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= product.product_name %></td>
        <td><%= product.chemical %></td>
       </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<%= paginate @registered_products %>
```

My partial for unregistered products is the same, replace @registered_products with @unregistered products.

*index.html.erb*

```
<h2>Registered Products</h2>
<%= render partial: "registered" %>
<h2>Unregistered Products</h2>
<%= render partial: "unregistered" %>
```

**What I tried**

I was looking through the Kaminari documentation and noticed that arrays can be paginated. So I tried that. Below are the modified files.

*Controller*

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
 def index
  registered_products = Product.where(product_type: 0).to_a
  unregistered_products = Product.where(product_type: 1).to_a

  @registered_products_array =  Kaminari.paginate_array(registered_products).page(params[:page]).per(10)
  @unregistered_products_array = Kaminari.paginate_array(unregistered_products).page(params[:page]).per(10)
 end
end
```

Every other relevant file is the same just substitute with the new global variables created. The problem still persists.

So my questions is how do I fix this problem and is it the problem occurring because I'm paginating the same object multiple times in the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this problem is happening is because you are using the same `params[:page]` attribute to navigate through the pages. This results in the same number being passed to both the queries for your `Product` model. You will need to do this instead to get it working.

Partial for registered page:

```
...
<%= paginate @registered_products, param_name: :registered_page_no %>
```

And in the unregistered page partial, you will have to do the same, but with a unique name like `unregistered_page_no`

In your controller, all you need to do is this:

```rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @registered_products = Product.where(product_type: 0).page params[:registered_page_no]
  @unregistered_products = Product.where(product_type: 1).page params[:unregistered_page_no]
 end
end
```

To know more about `param_name`, read the docs: https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#changing-the-parameter-name-param_name-for-the-links

Comment: Thank you @bitsapien, that was the problem. I didn't understand what 'params_name' was supposed to be but after looking through the Kaminari documentation I now understand. Thanks again!